# Double Nested "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered a problem today that i'm not sure how to deal with efficiently. As you can see in the code below there are three buttons, when one of them is clicked they all move to a designated spot, and then *the button that was clicked* changes color.

This was what I was hoping to achieve initially, however the background-color changes instantly without giving the buttons a chance to "arrive at their destinations". I tried to combat this by using a setTimeout(), but the nested function does not recognize the `this`.

```
$('.groupOfButtons').on('click', function(){
    $('#oneButton').animate({
        left:"425px",
        top:"-=24px"    
    }, 1000)
    $('#anotherButton').animate({
        left:"273px",
        top:"+=5px" 
    }, 1000)
    $('#oneMoreButton').animate({
        left:"137px",
        top:"+=34px"    
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'})}, 1000)    // here!
    })
})
```

If someone could give me a workaround that would be great! But in the meantime I'm curious about double nested `this`'s. How would one use it within one or more functions? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the `setTimeout` function callback, `this` references the global `window` object.

You need to capture the value of `this` outside of that scope:

```
$('.groupOfButtons').on('click', function(){
    var self = this;

    $('#oneButton').animate({
        left:"425px",
        top:"-=24px"    
    }, 1000)
    $('#anotherButton').animate({
        left:"273px",
        top:"+=5px" 
    }, 1000)
    $('#oneMoreButton').animate({
        left:"137px",
        top:"+=34px"    
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(self).css({'background-color': 'green'});
    }, 1000);
});
```

Also, as [Félix pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966124/double-nested-this/33966141?noredirect=1#comment55690309_33966141) in the comments, you can also change the value of `this` by using the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on the function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Very pretty solution, thank you. Does this mean you would need to keep declaring a variable for each nest?

Comment: @AdamSalma Yes. However, if you're using ES6 (possibly with a preprocessor), you can use an arrow function, which binds the outer `this` value. Long story short, you can do this: `setTimeout(() => $(this).css(...), 1000)`.

Comment: @AdamSalma Most likely. It depends how the function is called. This article may be useful for learning about scoping in JS: http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Or just use `.bind(this)` on the inner function.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the actual issue, keep a reference to which button was clicked, while `this` still refers to it.

Also .... `setTimeout()` will sort of do the job but leaves the timing somewhat to chance. For guaranteed timing, use [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to aggregate them.

```
$('.groupOfButtons').on('click', function() {
    var clickedButton = $(this); // keep a reference to which button was clicked
    var promise1 = $('#oneButton').animate({
        left:"425px",
        top:"-=24px"    
    }, 1000).promise();
    var promise2 = $('#anotherButton').animate({
        left:"273px",
        top:"+=5px" 
    }, 1000).promise();
    var promise3 = $('#oneMoreButton').animate({
        left:"137px",
        top:"+=34px"    
    }, 1000).promise();
    $.when(promise1, promise2, promise3).then(function() {
        clickedButton.css('backgroundColor', 'green')); // here use the reference made earlier.
    });
});
```

This will guarantee that the color change happens when all the buttons have arrived at their new positions, even if some computer glitch delays one or all of them.